# Can I use Cloudflare to remove GPS location data from the EXIF metadata of images?

Tags: cloudflare

I'm running a website where users can upload photos. A lot of users don't realise that photos contain metadata like GPS location data. I would like to strip out the GPS location EXIF metadata from any image served to the browser, so that it never leaks to any malicious user.

Is this possible to implement using Cloudflare's proxy services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cloudflare Polish](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000607372-Using-Cloudflare-Polish-to-compress-images) does remove image metadata, including EXIF GPS location metadata, but it doesn't guarantee to do this all of the time. So, **I would *not* rely on Cloudflare Polish for security**. It's meant a performance feature, not as a security/privacy feature.

Cloudflare Polish compresses images, removing any metadata, and stores the compressed and stripped image in its cache. It only serves this compressed and stripped image when serving the image from the cache. If the browser asks for an image, and that image isn't in Cloudflare's cache yet, the browser will receive the uncompressed image with all its original metadata!

(You can see if the image has been served from Cloudflare cache's by checking for the `cf-cache-status` header in the response. You can see if Cloudflare Polish has run by checking for the `cf-polished` header in the response.)

There are more reasons not to rely on Cloudflare Polish for this security use-case: Cloudflare Polish's implementation might change in the future, or you might turn off Cloudflare Polish, forgetting that you were relying on it to strip out private GPS location data.

Instead, **I recommend processing the image files to remove the EXIF location metadata, making sure that the original image file is deleted or overwritten**. That way, there is no chance that the GPS location data will ever be leaked.